# MySQL: INNER JOIN vs. separate queries in case of fixed amount of entries in one of the tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Here is my question.

Option 1:

```
SELECT B.some_field FROM A 
INNER JOIN B 
ON A.id = B.a_id
WHERE ((A.field1 = '1' AND  A.field2 = '2')
OR (A.field1 = '2' AND  A.field2 = '1'))
```

Option 2:

```
$id1 = SELECT id FROM A WHERE A.field1 = '1' AND  A.field2 = '2'
$id2 = SELECT id FROM A WHERE A.field1 = '2' AND  A.field2 = '1'

SELECT B.some_field FROM B WHERE B.a_id = '$id1' OR B.a_id = '$id2'
```

This is of course a pseudo code, $id1 and $id2 should contain the values of A.id of the corresponding rows.

Which on has a better performance?

The reason I'm asking is that I know there are only two rows in A which fit the WHERE condition, so I'm afraid that joining the tables will result in an overhead of MySQL going over a huge table which consist of each row in A for each row in B. Is this really the way INNER JOIN behaves?

I'll be more specific: In my case the primary key of A is (field1, field2). Is  MySQL smart enough to conclude that `WHERE ((A.field1 = '1' AND  A.field2 = '2') OR (A.field1 = '2' AND  A.field2 = '1'))` won't yield more than two rows so it will first extract these row/s and won't create a table of all the rows in B for each row in A?

I've tried to find a similar question in SO with no success.

Comment: let's start with this. would you agree with its output?   http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I got your question, But this link seems to answer my first question. The main question though was the second one.

Comment: the question about performance ?

Comment: Yes. My question is whether I should use one SELECT with an INNER JOIN or separate SELECTs. since I'm interested only in two rows in A, at the most, it doesn't make sense to me to ask MySql to create a row for each row in A per each row in B, which are A.NumOfRows * B.NumOfRows .

Comment: in general never go with 3 selects when you can let the rdbms optimized it for you. let it do it's work, it is quicker in general than a programmer trying to do the likes of Option2 (again, in general)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 has better performance.

Since your `( field1, field2 )` is a primary key, and you have the same thing in the where clause. So what MySQL will do is, it will first filter out on your `Table A` and you will get just 2 rows from that. After that join is pretty simple.

Still in case of any doubt use the `EXPLAIN` command. [See `EXPLAIN` command here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)

Comment: This is exactly what I asked. Could you please add a reference to your explanation about MySQL behavior in this case?

Comment: try running EXPLAIN command.. That would explain MySQL's behaviour.

Comment: +1 for adding the EXPLAIN command. It seems very useful in general.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you will get multiple rows back from table B which makes sense to me at least. you are asking for the B.some_field that matches the qualifying id's from A where fields are 1,2 or 2,1 as seen here:   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ff33/1

as for performance, go with your Option1 cause your primary key is a composite and you have 1 select (with a join) versus 3 selects using variables

Comment: I understood this. But my question is that perhaps in this case 3 SELECTs are preferred to avoid the creation of unnecessary rows within the mysql. Since I'm interested only in two rows of A (at the most), it doesn't make sense to me to ask MySql to create a row for each row in A per each row in B, which are A.NumOfRows * B.NumOfRows

Comment: first off maybe your terminology has me a little stumped. you are creating rows, the selects are just bringing back the result set not creating rows. as i am sure you know. are you suggesting that you do not want to create the rows or are you referring to the result set? next, as i don't know your data but assume B has valid some_field as in my output on sqlfiddle, isnt that output what you are looking for (in my example 3 rows in the result set) ?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. I'll try to explain better. Using INNER JOIN, MySQL goes over a huge number of possible rows and searches for a match. The rows I'm talking about are a combination of A's rows and B's rows. This search takes to explore A.number_of_rows * B.number_of_rows. Using three SELECTs, the search will be done only along twice the length of B (for both results of the first SELECT), so we have only the first SELECT across A plus the second one which takes to explore twice the length of B.

Comment: that is not the way it will behave. you said you have a primary key on field1, field2. as those values are in your where clause, the db engine will find them almost instantly via the index. you make it sound like it is doing a table scan which it is not

Comment: Yeah, Manu already said that. Many thanks for all the explanations. Upvoted.